# Add Additional Objects to JSON Encoded Array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I am currently using a JSON encoded array to display the users in my database for an auto-suggest feature.

It looks something like this:

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM users");

$json = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $json['name'] = $row['name'];
        $json['id'] = $row['id'];
        $data[] = $json;
    }

print json_encode($data);
```

This returns:

```
[{"id":"81","name":"John Doe"},{"id":"82","name":"Jane Doe"}]
```

My question is somewhat 2-fold:

**First**, how would I manually add an additional object to this output?  For example, let's say I wanted to add:  `{"id":"444","name":"A New Name"}`

Thus, it'd look like:

```
[{"id":"81","name":"John Doe"},{"id":"82","name":"Jane Doe"},{"id":"444","name":"A New Name"}]
```

**Second**, let's say I also wanted to add more objects to the array from a separate table as well, such as:

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT id, title FROM another_table");

$json = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $json['name'] = $row['title'];
        $json['id'] = $row['id'];
        $data[] = $json;
    }

print json_encode($data);
```

This way I could have both tables populated in the JSON array, thus, showing up as additional options in my autosuggest.

Hopefully this makes sense, as I've tried hard to articulate what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks!

Comment: And why don't you add them to your array before you do the json_encode? That would make more sense to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just keep pushing to the `$data` array.

```
$json = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $json['name'] = $row['name'];
        $json['id'] = $row['id'];
        $data[] = $json;
    }

$custom = array('name'=>'foo', 'id' => 'bar');
$data[] = $custom;
```

Then at the very end, do your `json_encode`. Assuming you're not referring to merging it in the JS itself with multiple ajax calls.

And if you have separate scripts, combine them in one php page.

Comment: Thanks Meder.  Easier than I thought it'd be.

Answer (score 4):

Try in this way:-

```
$temp = json_encode($json);  //$json={"var1":"value1","var2":"value2"}   
$temp=substr($temp,0,-1);
$temp.=',"variable":"'.$value.'"}';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the JSON (text), but it's much easier to modify the array before you encode it. 
Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in any of these fields, but I'll try and see if I can help.  Try one of these:

Option 1 (I don't know how unions work in mysql):

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM users union SELECT id, name FROM (SELECT id, title as name from another_table) as T2"); 


    $json = array(); 

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) { 
            $json['name'] = $row['name']; 
            $json['id'] = $row['id']; 
        }

    $json['name'] = 'A new name';
    $json['id'] = '444';
    $data[] = $json; 

    print json_encode($data);
```

I've never done PHP, so I'm making assumptions.  I've also never used MySql, so there's more assumptions.

Option 2:

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM users"); 


    $json = array(); 

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) { 
            $json['name'] = $row['name']; 
            $json['id'] = $row['id']; 
        }

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT id, title from another_table"); 


        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) { 
            $json['name'] = $row['title']; 
            $json['id'] = $row['id']; 
        }

    $json['name'] = 'A new name';
    $json['id'] = '444';
    $data[] = $json; 

    print json_encode($data);
```

Hope this helps.