# PHP - How to add more objects to JSON Encoded Array

Tags: php, json

i have json encoded in php its output like this.

```
[{"city":"Asasqewq"},{"city":"New Brunswick"},{"city":"Jersey City"},{"city":"Summit"},{"city":"Edison"},{"city":"Hillside"},{"city":"East Orange"}]
```

and

```
{"city":"New City 1"},{"city":"New City 2"}
```

How to merge those 2 json data objects to output like this?

```
 [{"city":"Asasqewq"},{"city":"New Brunswick"},{"city":"Jersey City"},{"city":"Summit"},{"city":"Edison"},{"city":"Hillside"},{"city":"East Orange"}, {"city":"New City 1"},{"city":"New City 2"}]
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: DUPLICATED [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504278/add-additional-objects-to-json-encoded-array][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504278/add-additional-objects-to-json-encoded-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json_str = '[{"city":"Asasqewq"},{"city":"New Brunswick"},{"city":"Jersey City"},{"city":"Summit"},{"city":"Edison"},{"city":"Hillside"},{"city":"East Orange"}]
';

$json_arr = json_decode($json_str, true);

$json_arr[] = array('city' => 'NewCity1');
$json_arr[] = array('city' => 'NewCity2');

$json_str = json_encode($json_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be using `substr`

```
$json = '[{"city":"Asasqewq"},{"city":"New Brunswick"},{"city":"Jersey City"},{"city":"Summit"},{"city":"Edison"},{"city":"Hillside"},{"city":"East Orange"}]';
$new = '{"city":"New City 1"},{"city":"New City 2"}';
$json = substr($json,0,-1) . ',' . $new . ']';
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you encode the array add the 2 cities to it, then in code it.

```
$theArray[] = array("city"=>"New City 1");
$theArray[] = array("city"=>"New City 2");
$json = json_encode($theArray);
```

Now if you don't have access to the object you can decode it add the items the encode it again.

```
$theArray = json_decode($json);
$theArray[] = array("city"=>"New City 1");
$theArray[] = array("city"=>"New City 2");
$json = json_encode($theArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$je --> your JSON Data...

$jn = json_decode($je,true);
  array_push($jn, array('city1' => 'City 1'),array('city2' => 'New City 2'));
```